# How to install World of Warcraft?

Tags: wine, games, software-installation

I need a tutorial on how to install World of Warcraft for Ubuntu.

Comment: I've been trying to do this on different ubuntu I even tried on Mint. Tried Playonlinux, trial of crossover and just Wine 1.6.2 and Wine 1.7 can anyone give me some assistance. I'm new to linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
First [Download](http://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/3.8.10/PlayOnLinux_3.8.10.deb) and install(by double clicking) PlayOnLinux 
then open PlayOnLinux (Applications -> PlayOnLinux) and click install.

[image]

Then select Games -> World of Warcraft and follow the on-screen instructions.

[image]
[image]

Then run the game from Applications -> Playonlinux -> World of Warcraft

Comment: after installing you should launch World of Warcraft with the flag "-opengl". Example "wine Wow.exe -opengl" or "wine Launcher.exe -opengl"

Comment: @TheDarktonik playonlinux already configures the wine registry to use opengl :)

Answer (score 11):

Go to software center, install playonlinux, and then once it's installed and you open it from your menu (or alt+f2), click install
[image]

choose games, and find your WoW version to install =).
[image]

Then follow the on screen instructions. If you get further problems the best place to look is the forums on winehq.org

Answer (score 3):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WorldofWarcraft

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go through PlayOnLinux. Simply download the Windows installer from Battle.net and install as you would on Windows. Worked like a charm for me.