# Is it possible to play World of Warcraft?

Tags: games

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install World of Warcraft?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10779/how-to-install-world-of-warcraft)

It's the only reason I preserve Windows on my computer.
However, is it possible to play the game in Ubuntu smoothly?

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/16733/how-can-i-adjust-the-resolution-of-individual-wine-programs And you actually do not need playonlinux to install wow. After you have install wine you just install world of warcraft the normal way. Double click the installer and you are done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/10779/how-to-install-world-of-warcraft

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is possible.
First [Download](http://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/3.8.10/PlayOnLinux_3.8.10.deb) and install(by double clicking) PlayOnLinux 
then open PlayOnLinux (Applications -> PlayOnLinux) and click install.

[image]

Then select Games -> World of Warcraft and follow the on-screen instructions.

[image]
[image]

Then run the game from Applications -> Playonlinux -> World of Warcraft

Answer (score 3):

[The official AppDB page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20549) holds one of the best maintained guides. That's your best bet for getting it set up and optimised.

Comment: playonlinux takes care of everything (even setting wow to use opengl).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Ubuntu WOW page "WorldofWarcraft" at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WorldofWarcraft