# switching over to ubuntu wanting advise

Tags: firefox, gimp

I am planing on switching over to ubuntu on a older laptop I have that has aa few issues right now I figured wiping the os clean was an easier move. Since I don't have the money for a new lap top right now.

I know I will need to back up my stuff thats not an issue what I am wondering there are several programs I use I am wondering if they will work on ubuntu or not

Namely: Firefox, Adobe Reader, Microsoft Office, Gimp, World of Warcraft.

these are the main programs I want to bring over and keep I am wondering if they can be used on ubuntu and if I need to do anything special to make them work. Any help at all would be wonderful thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider Lubuntu or Xubuntu for an old laptop, they're more lightweight and easier on the hardware.

- Firefox is fully supported
- the Gimp is fully supported
- there are several alternatives for Adobe Reader and there is also a linux version
- Microsoft Office, I've heard about people getting it operational under Linux/Wine, but it is not supported by Microsoft. Microsoft Office 2010 (Word and Excel) will install in the latest version of Wine (the compatibility layer that allows windows programs to run in linux).  LibreOffice is an alternative that works very well. LibreOffice does not have an Outlook alternative, but you can use Thunderbird for that or Evolution.
- World of Warcraft. There is a nice [how-to install here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10779/how-to-install-world-of-warcraft).

Comment: Not sure if the Microsoft license allows you to run MS Office under Wine. Probably not, but it would be a legal issue not a technical issue.

Comment: lol I ironically did find the World of Warcraft instruction briefly after posting this.